# How to define context url rest web service deployed as ear in weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, rest, war, ear

I have REST web service deployed as EAR file on weblogic. The desired endpoint URL of webservice should be `/v1/users/{id}/groups`. parameter `id` is dynamic value.

I have defined context root as `v1` in `application.xml`. In `web.xml` i have defined url-pattern as `/users/*`

Web service class has annotation as `@Path("/users")`  and web method annotation is `@Path("/{id}/groups")`.

But with this configuration, the URL is coming as `v1/users/users/25e153e2be50/groups`. I tried removing `url-pattern` in `web.xml` and `context root` in `application.xml` but server is throwing validation errors.

What change do i need to do so that I can have the desired endpoint as `/v1/users/{id}/groups`

Answer (score 0):

modified application.xml with `<context-root>/</context-root>` to get the required endpoint.